# How to compare a value from UITextField against a CoreData value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am implementing a simple Login authentication inside my app by using core data.
But login functionality works only if i enter the correct username and password,otherwise i am getting an **exception :**

`"[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'"`

I understood that it is because of my incorrect code(i.e.,i am checking only for equality).But i dont know how to check for inequality.

Can any one help me to **perform** this **login authentication using core data**...

**Code :**

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(employeeID = %@)",
                             self.employeeId.text];
    [request setPredicate:pred];
    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    matches=[objects objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"qweertyuio%@",[matches valueForKey:@"employeeID"]);

    if ([objects count] == 0) 
    {
        status.text = @"No matches";
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *str=self.employeeId.text;
        NSString *str1=[matches valueForKey:@"employeeID"];
        matches=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([str isEqualToString:str1]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"hai");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this below:-

```
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if ([objects count] > 0) {
    matches=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"qweertyuio%@",[matches valueForKey:@"employeeID"]);
NSString *str=self.employeeId.text;
    NSString *str1=[matches valueForKey:@"employeeID"];
 matches=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([str isEqualToString:str1]) {
   NSLog(@"hai");
    }
}    
else
{
status.text = @"No matches";
 }
```

Comment: Hi....I know this is a long post but this has proved very useful to me. Would you mind explaining this part of the code "matches=[objects objectAtIndex:0];" . I do not understand what this part is doing. Also how would you recommend adding a logout functionality, once the user has logged in?

Comment: Objects is an array which contains group of dictionary whose key is employeeID. So extracting the same as a string and doing the comparison of the two string accordingly.

Comment: That I got....I am confused at the point objectAtIndex:0. Doesn't this line of code mean ONLY getting the first value of an array? So, if 5 users are created, won't core data get the login details of the user at index:0 no matter whose username and password is entered?

Answer (score 0):

You try to access `[objects objectAtIndex:0]` before checking if the fetch was successful. You should deal with `NSErrors` and check if it's not `nil`/not empty before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You have out `matches = [objects objectAtIndex:0];` before check if exists any object on `coredata`. So, if there isn't any object, you get that error `([__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]:` index 0 beyond bounds for empty `array`').

Delete these lines:

```
matches=[objects objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"qweertyuio%@",[matches valueForKey:@"employeeID"]);
```

Comment: Yes i understand but my problem is in NSPredicate i am checking employeeID=uitextfield.text,but i dont know what to do if they are not equal

Comment: if i delete that lines i am getting null as output

Comment: If they are not equal you must give an answer to the user (i.e. an alert view) showing that the user isn't registered or the user has enter a wrong username or password.